# latex interpretation of selected German and Latin as well as mathematics-physics characters via matlab-prettifier

Tags: symbols, german, matlab-prettifier

I want to append some matlab code to a tex document and I use the matlab-prettifier package for that. I updated my miktex installation yesterday and I am now forced to use the \UseRawInputEncoding code line. Everything works fine for the German and Latin symbols I have in my matlab code, except for the degree sign, which comes out as an r with an inverted hat above, regardless of whether I use the literate substitution approach or not. Any suggestions on how to solve this elegantly would be welcome.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\UseRawInputEncoding

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
  literate=%
    {°}{\textdegree{}}1%
}

\lstinputlisting[]{matlab_code.m}

\end{document}
```

and my matlab_code.m file reads as:

```
% ----------------------------    
% Rö and Mé (T = 23°C)
var_1 = 10;
```

Obviously, I can write degree instead of ° in the matlab file and substitute that by \textdegree, but I would like to bring changes to the matlab code to a minimum and actually use the degree symbol, whose use comes much more naturally than that of the corresponding text. Is it possible to directly read in tex and via matlab-prettifier a ° symbol written on a matlab file, rather than "going around" by substituting the corresponding degree text by the actual symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no coverage of UTF-8 by listings, unfortunately. But `\UseRawInputEncoding` is not the right tool.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  style=Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle=\mlttfamily\footnotesize,
  literate=
    {°}{\textdegree{}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {é}{{\'e}}1
}

\lstinputlisting[]{matlab_code.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, here's what I get with `minted`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\inputminted[frame=single,linenos]{matlab}{matlab_code.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot **@egreg**! However, for some unknown reason, I get a compilation error with the _matlab-prettifier_ package, if I do not use `\UseRawInputEncoding`, namely a `Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "F6` type of error. This all started after I reinstalled miktex, before that I didn't have that kind of error. As for the _minted_ package it looks good, but I am not able to compile as I first need to be able to invoke `-shell-escape`. Normally, I compile with cygwin, not with TexStudio, so I would be grateful if you could tell me how to compile the _minted_-related code on cygwin

Comment: Alright. Meanwhile, I could almost! compile the _minted_-related code by using the command `pdflatex --shell-escape document_name`. However, it seems I need to have _pygmentize_ installed. Does that mean I have to install Python first? Or is there a shorter way to get to those **pygments**? Not familiar with Python..............

Comment: coming back to the _matlab-prettifier_ approach: the problem clearly is that my latex architecture cannot make sense of ö, é and ° on the left handside of each literate entry! I would be grateful if I could get any help on how to fix this..............

Comment: I will in the meantime, try to install Python, set it to the appropriate path and get that **pygmentize.exe** going..............

Comment: still on the _matlab-prettifier_ approach: the only way it currently works for me is if I have text, not "special characters" written in the matlab code, i.e. if I for instance have "oe" instead of "ö" in the matlab code, and then use literate with `{oe}{{\"o}}1` to finally have latex putting the ö in the .pdf document; which is less than ideal..............

Comment: OK. After some research, I found the reason for my error with the _matlab-prettifier_ approach in here: [link](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf). The problem can been solved by adding `\usepackage[encoding]{inputenc}` to the preamble, with encoding = latin1 OR cp1252.

Comment: so, now for the sake of completeness, I just need to get those Python **pygments**..............

Comment: @Euclides Be sure to save your files in UTF-8.

Comment: **@egreg**: alright, thanks! Ideally, I update my matlab version as well. From what I could find out, from 2020 on all matlab .m files are automatically encoded in UTF-8.